# #define a char array without null termination in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a industry safety product that requires very fast startup time. I am trying to follow an industry standard for outputting an ASCII file. In order to speed up this file formatting step, I have used #define's to create several character arrays in static memory. Here's a small section for example:

```
#define COMTRADE_STATION_ID         "Station Name,Device ID,1999\r\n"
#define COMTRADE_CHANNEL_COUNT      "10,10A,0D\r\n"
#define COMTRADE_FREQUENCY          "60\r\n"
#define COMTRADE_FILE_TYPE          "BINARY\r\n1\r\n"

struct TS_ComtradeConfig
{
    const char StationID[sizeof(COMTRADE_STATION_ID)];
    const char ChannelCount[sizeof(COMTRADE_CHANNEL_COUNT)];
    char Frequency[sizeof(COMTRADE_FREQUENCY)];
    const char FileType[sizeof(COMTRADE_FILE_TYPE)];
};

TS_ComtradeConfig ConfigFile =
{
        {COMTRADE_STATION_ID},
        {COMTRADE_CHANNEL_COUNT},
        {COMTRADE_FREQUENCY},
        {COMTRADE_FILE_TYPE}
};
```

And here's some basic code I've been using for printing it out.

```
for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex < sizeof(ConfigFile); nIndex++)
{
    printf("%c", ((char*)(ConfigFile.StationID))[nIndex]);
}
```

This works fine for generating the static char arrays, and it works fine for printing out the entire ConfigFile as a whole, but the char arrays are null-terminated, which means the end result does not meet the industry standard. It seems that the #define strings are being null-terminated by the pre-processor. Is there any way around this? Or any other methods for doing this sort of high speed operation?

Comment: copy characters into those arrays

Comment: That was my previous implementation, which added a considerable slow-down to the startup time.

Comment: You could use a char * to point at ConfigFile and do
if (*p) printf("%c", *p ); 
p++

Comment: Did you try: const char StationID[sizeof(COMTRADE_STATION_ID)-1];

Comment: Yes, during the creation of ConfigFile it gives a compilation error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Rob Please refrain from advising people to overflow buffers. Everyone else, please refrain from upvoting comments advising people to overflow buffers.

Comment: @Rob: Yeah overflowing arrays is fun

Comment: _"It seems that the #define strings are being null-terminated by the pre-processor"_ Yes, string literals are null-terminated. It doesn't have all that much to do with the `#define`, though...

Comment: This question is unclear. Is the output the problem, or the layout/contents of the struct? What else will you be doing with it? Which "industry standard" are you attempting to adhere to?

Comment: @PeterSchneider The issue with that is the ConfigFile struct itself contains several \0's within it. If it was one giant #define it could work, but several sections of the file need to be editable.

Comment: That's a really silly way to define a struct format if that's true

Comment: Oh I missed that. You print the whole struct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am following IEEE 37.111-1999 for Transient Data Exchange. The output of the ConfigFile is a big ASCII file. The issue is the numerous null terminators that are populated in the file if I follow this method.

Comment: It's very silly, but most embedded systems are silly.

Comment: @rightføld: That's a buffer overflow caught at compile-time. And it works in C, btw (maybe that was Rob was thinking about, I had the same thought and was a little surprised that it doesn't also work in C++).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought that if you gave exactly the correct number of characters in a string for a char array it didn't add the null

Comment: @Rob: Well, you were wrong. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I more was using printf for debugging purposes, the hardware drivers are expecting a char array in memory. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about string concatenation:

```
#define COMTRADE_STATION_ID         "Station Name,Device ID,1999\r\n"
#define COMTRADE_CHANNEL_COUNT      "10,10A,0D\r\n"
#define COMTRADE_FREQUENCY          "60\r\n"
#define COMTRADE_FILE_TYPE          "BINARY\r\n1\r\n"

#define COMTRADE_ALL COMTRADE_STATION_ID COMTRADE_CHANNEL_COUNT COMTRADE_FREQUENCY COMTRADE_FILE_TYPE

    // no struct, plain char array, no intervening nulls (but a trailing one)
char[sizeof(COMTRADE_ALL)] comTradeAll = COMTRADE_ALL;
```

Comment: You could take it a step further by modifying `TS_ComtradeConfig` to contain that concatenated string, and then change StationID, ChannelCount, etc to just be pointers into that long array (and add some size members so the proper size of each member is known). If that makes any sense.

Comment: Just tested this out, worked perfectly. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex < sizeof(ConfigFile); nIndex++)
> {
>     printf("%c", ((char*)(ConfigFile.StationID))[nIndex]);
> }
> ```

I have no idea why you're printing it out like that, `char` by `char`. If there's padding in that struct, you're in for some trouble.

Why not just iterate through the members of `ConfigFile` and `fwrite` them? Replace the whole loop with:

```
// Add a -1 to the size to skip the \0
fwrite(ConfigFile.StationID, sizeof(ConfigFile.StationID) - 1, 1, stdout);
fwrite(ConfigFile.ChannelCount, sizeof(ConfigFile.ChannelCount) - 1, 1, stdout);
fwrite(ConfigFile.Frequency, sizeof(ConfigFile.Frequency) - 1, 1, stdout);
fwrite(ConfigFile.FileType, sizeof(ConfigFile.FileType) - , 1, stdout);
```

Not only is the code more clear (since you aren't doing your weird char pointer hack), it prints out exactly what you want. It also might be slightly more efficient, as you don't have a formatting string to process (it just does a data dump).

Comment: My reasoning for printing out like that is to give a hardware comm bus a contiguous piece of memory to read. Speed was again my reasoning for this method.

Comment: @jetbomber117: I'd like to see you profile the two and see which one is faster. I'll bet the `for` loop is slower than these `fwrite`s (though I'm curious to know if I'm wrong).

Comment: I agree that this would be faster in a typical file system, but this is more for an application which has limited access to a hardware bus. Repeated polling is not ideal.

Comment: @jetbomber117: I understand that. I've worked on some small systems that have quirky bottlenecks. I'd still like to see an actual comparison of speed, though. But I have another idea that I'll edit into my answer. [edit: Peter's idea was what I had in mind, except with additional offset pointers and size members so you could get each property individually as well as collectively).